# How can you move a parameter pack and function pointer into a struct?

Tags: c++, function, struct, variadic-templates, wrapper

I've been running around stack overflow and google for hours now. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to store a function pointer and it's arguments in a wrapper struct.

The following class wraps a function (in this case a packaged task with templated returntypes and arguments). The main part of the wrapper is listed below.

EDIT: The reason why I don't use std::function is because the wrapper (ThreadTask) wraps a std::packaged_task that gets moved into a threadsafe deque. Packaged_task is move-construbable and does not support copy, which std::function do. Therefore I make a custom wrapper.

The compiler gives an error and states that the function doesn't take 0 arguments. But I don't know how to pass along the arguments / store them.

```
class ThreadTask {
    struct BaseInterface {

        virtual void Call() = 0;
        virtual ~BaseInterface() {};
    };
    std::unique_ptr<BaseInterface> mImplementation;

    template <typename F, typename...Args>
    struct BaseFunc : BaseInterface {
        F func;

        BaseFunc(F&& f, Args... args) : func(std::move(f)) {}
        void Call() { func(); }
    };
};
```

I've tried unpacking the arguments in different ways, but I can't seem to make it work. I think I should forward them some how by std::forward, but i can't figure out were to store the parameters

Comment: Put the arguments into a tuple. Then, for the function call convert the tuple back to a parameter pack.

Comment: nowadays you really should not bind/store argument yourself unless you have good reason. in this case, just let the user write the bind (possibly with lambda) and everything is clear.

Comment: Use `std::function` to store the bound `f` with `args...`

Comment: @273K : I would rather not use std::function

Comment: 1. You have not mentioned it the question. [Edit] the question to add addition info. 2. If you don't use it, you have to implement its functionality in your struct, thus why don't use it?

Comment: @Martin the point of std::function is that it does pretty much what you are doing. I suppose the reason to avoid it is that it allocates heap memory?

Comment: Or get rid of `Args...` and pass (capturing) lambda.

Comment: Why isn't the caller passing a capturing lambda that already has the arguments bound in it?  But if that can't be done for some reason, you could store the `Args...` in a `std::tuple`, and then invoke the function using [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) passing the tuple in for unpacking-to-parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using `std::function` but if you don't want to use that for some reason, you could extend your current class to store the arguments in `std::tuple` and then use `std::apply` to "unpack" and call the function with the stored arguments.

Example:

```cpp
class ThreadTask {
public:
    struct BaseInterface {
        virtual ~BaseInterface() = default;
        virtual void operator()() = 0;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<BaseInterface> mImplementation;

    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    struct BaseFunc : BaseInterface {
        BaseFunc(F f, Args... args)
            : func(std::move(f)), m_args{std::move(args)...} {}

        void operator()() override {
            std::apply(func, m_args); 
        }

        F func;
        std::tuple<Args...> m_args;
    };
};
```

Usage example:

```cpp
void foo(int x, double y) {
    std::cout << "got " << x << " and " << y << '\n'; 
}

int main() {
    ThreadTask::BaseFunc bf{&foo, 12, 3.14159};

    bf();
}
```

Note: I changed `Call()` to `operator()()` which seemed more appropriate and made the members `public` for the demo.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4GEao4x4e)

Comment: @TedLyngmo The reason why i don't use std::function is because the wrapper (ThreadTask) is for packaged_tasks that gets submitted into a threadsafe deque (with a number of ThreadTasks inside it). Packaged_tasks have to be move constructable and not copy constructable, therefor i create the wrapper. I'm too much of an c++ idiot to know if

Comment: @Martin So, you probably want to implement something like the C++23 [`std::move_only_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function) - or perhaps use [`boost::executor_function`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/asio/detail/executor_function.hpp) - at least as inspiration

Comment: @Martin I forgot to ask if my suggested solution worked out of if there's something I left unanswered?

Comment: @TedLyngmo : Yes. You pointed me in the right direction. I ended up using fn2::unique_function as a premade wrapper with seemingly good performance instead. I also tried out the c++23 std::move_only_function, but chose to run the aforementioned library instead. I also decided to ditch the packaged_task stuff and instead use a wrapping lambda, since passing arguments was a pain to manage for my newbie c++ brain. 
It was nice to see that tuples could handle parameterpackages if needed and learned a bit more about how c++ works!

Answer (score 1):

You could have also used [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) in order to unpack the tuple and pass it to the function.

```
class ThreadTask {
    struct BaseInterface {

        virtual void Call() = 0;
        virtual ~BaseInterface() {};
    };
    std::unique_ptr<BaseInterface> mImplementation;

    template <typename F, typename...Args>
    struct BaseFunc : BaseInterface {
        F func;
        std::tuple<Args...> _args;

        BaseFunc(F&& f, Args... args) : func(std::move(f)), _args(std::make_tuple(args...)) {}
        void Call() { 
            constexpr size_t tuple_size = sizeof...(_args);
            auto index_seq = std::make_index_sequence<tuple_size>();
            CallHelper(index_seq); 
        }
        template<size_t... Is>
        void CallHelper(std::index_sequence<Is...> indexes)
        {
            func(std::get<Is>(_args)...);
        }
    };
};
```

`std::get<Is>(_args)...` is a parameter pack expansion pattern which will get you `std::get<0>(_args), std::get<1>(_args), ..., std::get<n>(_args)`, which are the arguments you initially intended to use.

Comment: `std::tuple_size<decltype(_args)>::value` - Why not just `sizeof...(Args)` or `std::index_sequence_for<Args...`>? `CallHelper` - Isn't that just `std::apply()`?